# Included properties returns null

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto

I have a table named employee:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public int SupervisorId {get; set;}
        public int EmployeeStatusId{ get; set; }
        public EmployeeStatus EmployeeStatus{ get; set; }
    }
```

EmployeeStatus:

```
public class EmployeeStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

There is EmployeeStatusDto which is the same as base class and EmployeeDto:

```
 public class EmployeeDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SupervisorId {get; set;}
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapperConfig:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
                    .ForMember(e => e.StatusId, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.EmployeeStatus.Id))
                    .ForMember(e => e.StatusName, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.EmployeeStatus.Name));
```

And getting it out of context class in service:

```
    employees = await _context.Employees.Where(x => x.SupervisorId == supervisorId).Include(x => x.EmployeeStatus).ToListAsync();
List<EmployeeDto> result = _mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDto>>(employees);
```

Problem I have is that StatusName and StatusId are nulls:

[image: Status]

What am I missing there?

Comment: try this =>`_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Just a guess, add a `.ReverseMap();`

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html